# Imprimir información de un XML con SAX en JAVA

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, sax

Tengo este XML (un trozo dado que hay muchos mas jugadores y equipos):

```
…
<jugador posicio="44">
<nom>Amancio Amaro</nom>
<gols>119</gols>
<partits>344</partits>
<mitjana>0.35</mitjana>
<equips>
<equip>
<nom>Real Madrid C. F.</nom>
<gols>119</gols>
</equip>
</equips>
</jugador>
<jugador posicio="45">
<nom>Ronaldo</nom>
<gols>117</gols>
<partits>164</partits>
<mitjana>0.71</mitjana>
<equips>
<equip>
<nom>F. C. Barcelona</nom>
<gols>34</gols>
</equip>
<equip>
<nom>Real Madrid C. F.</nom>
<gols>83</gols>
</equip>
</equips>
</jugador>
...
```

Y mi objetivo es contar cuantos goles ha echo cada jugador y el total  de cada equipo, ejemplo seria asi (tambien mirando que un jugador ha estado en mas de un equipo):

```
Real Madrid C.F.: 202
     Amancio Amaro 119
     Ronaldo 83

F. C. Barcelona: 34
     Ronaldo 34
```

Mi Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Crear el parser
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser = spf.newSAXParser();
            // Processar el fitxer
            parser.parse(new File("golejadors.xml"), new Processar());
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("El fitxer no hi és");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Mi Processar.java (que de esta forma imprime todo):

```
public class Processar extends DefaultHandler {

    int numGoles = 0;
    boolean rebutNom = false;
    boolean rebutGol = false;
    boolean rebutEquip = false;

    public void startElement(String uri, String localname, String qName, Attributes atributs) {
        switch(qName) {
            case "equip":
                rebutEquip = true;
                break;
            case "nom":
                if (rebutEquip) {
                    rebutNom = true;
                    break;
                }
            case "gols":
                rebutGol = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length){
        String text = new String(ch, start, length);
        if (rebutNom) {
            rebutNom = false;
            System.out.println(text);
        }

    }

    public void endDocument() {
        System.out.println("\n----------------\n");
    }
}
```

No se como hacer para coger cada uno de los elementos y (aunque un jugador haya estado en mas de un equipo) los goles dependiendo del equipo y que salga como he enseñado antes.

Answer (score -1):

Viendo que la pregunta era realmente sobre el parser, estoy cambiando la respuesta:

El tema del `handler` del `SAX` parser es que te va a avisando cada vez que abre un tag, y cada vez que cierra un tag, así como cada vez que hay una lectura de caracteres.

En la lectura de caracteres hay que tener en cuenta que, dentro del mismo tag, pueden darse varias lecturas parciales, por lo que no puede asumirse que se tiene toda la información hasta que se cierra el tag.

Por otro lado, el handler solo te dice que tag se abrió o cerró y vos tenes que implementar la lógica de saber donde estás en el documento.

En tu ejemplo el handler te dirá que se abrió el tag `<nom>` pero vos tenés que llevar la cuenta de si ese tag es de `jugador` o de `equip` en base a los tags anteriores que se fueron abriendo y cerrando.

La lógica de seguir donde estás en el documento puede volverse muy engorrosa y puede hacerse de diferentes formas mas o menos artesanales. 
Esta lógica la dejo para que la impelemntes vos. Acá Simplemente voy a modificar el código para que veas como levantar la información con el parser.

Fijate los comentarios dentro del código ...

```
public class Processar extends DefaultHandler {
    // Para juntar los caracteres leidos entre tags.
    StringBuilder sb;

    int numGoles = 0;
    boolean rebutNom = false;
    boolean rebutGol = false;
    boolean rebutEquip = false;

    public void startElement(String uri, String localname, String qName, Attributes atributs) {
        // Reemplazamos el StringBuilder con cada nuevo tag
        sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Usar este switch junto con uno en endElement() para saber cual es el tag que se está procesando.
        switch(qName) {
            case "equip":
              rebutEquip = true;
              break;
            case "nom":
              if (rebutEquip) {
                rebutNom = true;
                break;
              }
            case "gols":
              rebutGol = true;
              break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        //Aca contás con la información del tag, cuando se cierra el mismo.

        //Para guardar temporalmente los datos leidos
        String nom = "";
        String gols = "";

        switch(qName){
        case "nom": 
           nom = sb.toString().trim(); //Sacar los datos del StringBuilder
           break;
        case "gols": 
           gols = sb.toString.trim();  //Sacar los datos del StringBuilder
           break;
        }    

        //Aplicar la lógica para saber si son nombres de equipos o de jugadores y actuar en consecuencia

    }

    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length){
        // Juntar los caracters (nombre, cantidad de goles)
        sb.append(ch,start,length);
    }

    public void endDocument() {
        System.out.println("\n----------------\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Pero el problema esta en que no se como aplicar SAX en tu ejemplo